# Bootstrap, how to update a Div when using <a> and data-toggle and data-target

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and struggling with understanding the flow. I am looking to update a  section when an  is clicked.

Here is the code

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">
    <small class="pull-right text-muted"> 16.02.2015</small>
    <strong>Ann Smith</strong>
    <div class="small m-t-xs">
     <p>Survived not only five centuries, but also the leap scrambled it to make.</p>

    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to update a Div with tab1 with a content I get through another URL call. When I put href="my.html", the target div does not update. I think I am missing something simple in Bootstrap... I also tried data-target, but it did not work.

Any help / direction / tutorial would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @gkempkens

Here is what worked finally with tabs

```js
 $('a').click(function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();
    
  var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var href = this.hash;
    var pane = $(this);
  
  $(href).load(url,function(result){   
   console.log(result);
      pane.tab('show');
  });
  
 });
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">
    <small class="pull-right text-muted"> 16.02.2015</small>
    <strong>Ann Smith</strong>
    <div class="small m-t-xs">
     <p>Survived not only five centuries, but also the leap scrambled it to make.</p>

    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with out-of-the-box Bootstrap. I think you need to do something like this:

```
$('#tab-1').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var _this = this;
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var href = button.attr('href'); // Extract the href from the opener.
    if(typeof href !== 'undefined' ) {
        $.ajax( href ).done(function(html) {
            _this.html(html);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        });
    }
});
```

This will bind a show event to the target modal. From there you can load the page from the href. You could add some extra logic/checks to make sure the href isn't starting with #. Also handle the fail properly, when something goes wrong, but this should point you into the right direction. Hopes it helped.